# MS ACCESS Запрос SQL SELECT выборка данных из четырех таблиц

Tags: sql, ms-access

Есть четыре таблицы:

1. Main (ID (KEY), A1_ID, A2_ID, A3_ID);
2. A1 (A1_ID (KEY), NameA1);
3. A2 (A2_ID (KEY), NameA2);
4. A3 (A3_ID (KEY), NameA3);

В таблице Main поля A1_ID, A2_ID, A3_ID могут быть пустыми = `NULL`.
Мне необходим запрос SELECT, чтобы получилась следующая таблица:

`Main.ID, A1.NameA1, A2.NameA2, A3.NameA3`,
где Main.ID например = 12

Я написал запрос:

```
SELECT Main.ID,
   A1.NameA1,
   A2.NameA2,
   A3.NameA3 
FROM Main 
  INNER JOIN A1 ON Main.A1_ID = A1.A1_ID 
  INNER JOIN A2 ON Main.A2_ID = A2.A2_ID 
  INNER JOIN A3 ON Main.A3_ID = A3.A3_ID 
WHERE Main.ID = 12
```

Но выдает ошибку:

> Ошибка синтаксиса (пропущен оператор) Main.A1_ID = A1.A1_ID INNER JOIN
>   A2 ON Main.A2_ID = A2.A2_ID INNER JOIN A3 ON Main.A3_ID = A3.A3_ID
>   WHERE Main.ID = 12

Заранее спасибо за помощь!

Comment: LEFT JOIN спасет отца русской демократии.

Comment: Я написал с его помощью запрос.                                              SELECT Main.ID
    ,A1.NameA1
    ,A2.NameA2
    ,A3.NameA3
FROM Main
INNER JOIN A1 ON Main.A1_ID = A1.A1_ID
INNER JOIN A2 ON Main.A2_ID = A2.A2_ID
INNER JOIN A3 ON Main.A3_ID = A3.A3_ID
WHERE Main.ID = 12                                                                                                   Но выдает ошибку Ошибка синтаксиса (пропущен оператор) Main.A1_ID = A1.A1_ID
INNER JOIN A2 ON Main.A2_ID = A2.A2_ID
INNER JOIN A3 ON Main.A3_ID = A3.A3_ID
WHERE Main.ID = 12

Comment: Чтобы учесть что поля могут быть равны NULL я переписал запрос. SELECT Main.ID ,A1.NameA1 ,A2.NameA2 ,A3.NameA3 FROM Main LEFT OUTER JOIN A1 ON Main.A1_ID = A1.A1_ID LEFT OUTER JOIN A2 ON Main.A2_ID = A2.A2_ID LEFT OUTER JOIN A3 ON Main.A3_ID = A3.A3_ID WHERE Main.ID = 12 Но выдает ошибку Ошибка синтаксиса (пропущен оператор) в выражении Main.A1_ID = A1.A1_ID LEFT OUTER JOIN A2 ON Main.A2_ID = A2.A2_ID LEFT OUTER JOIN A3 ON Main.A3_ID = A3.A3_ID WHERE Main.ID = 12

Comment: Аксесс требует строго попарных связываний. Расставьте скобки. А ещё лучше - постройте запрос визуально.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я не ошибаюсь, MS Access требует скобки при соединении таблиц. Таким образом, запрос должен выглядеть как:

```
SELECT Main.ID,
   A1.NameA1,
   A2.NameA2,
   A3.NameA3 
FROM ((Main 
  LEFT JOIN A1 ON Main.A1_ID = A1.A1_ID)
  LEFT JOIN A2 ON Main.A2_ID = A2.A2_ID)
  LEFT JOIN A3 ON Main.A3_ID = A3.A3_ID 
WHERE Main.ID = 12
```

Comment: СПАСИБО ОГРОМНОЕ!!! ТОЧНО!!! Я забыл про скобки!!!) Все работает!!!

Comment: @Maxwell всегда пожалуйста)